# WSO2 Integrator 6.3 - How to call sequence from other project?

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 Integrator version 6.3 and develop services using eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). I have 2 projects in my work space, one project is supposed to contain some core sequences that I want to use in the other project. But when I double click the called sequence from the proxy service for example to open it, Eclipse creates an empty sequence in the same project and calls it. Is there any solution for this issue because I don't want to put all my sequences in the same project.

Comment: I have a similar problem as yours. Did you find any solution for this? If yes can you share your solution here?

Answer (score 0):

there is always the 'switch to source view' fix where you can manually enter the named sequence as follows: `<sequence key="yourSharedSequence"/>`

I have to note here that it is usually inadvisable to do this since when you remove or redeploy the project your shared sequence is in, your other project(s) will momentarily not work anymore.

*edit: Used ' instead of backtick ` so the code part was not showing.*

Comment: isn't it possible to import the core sequences project into my actual main project using Maven just like how we do it in Java projects?

Comment: Well, worth a try, but my guess is that still doesn't work as it will try to deploy a sequence that's already there.